# Price based on location and size in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am developing a website in Opencart version 2.3. I have to change the price of the product based on user location and weight of the selected product. I am getting the User City from a popup in my home page. That stores the City name in session. I am storing the cities in a separate table. Every Product will have a weights of 250 grams, 500 grams and 1kg.

My requirement is to get the price of the item based on both location and weight. Each city will have different price for the same product.

Can someone suggest me how to achieve this. Explanation in a theoretical way is fine. I can code for that. I just need help with the approach.

Comment: So, you have a table with the city, product and price and another table with product and weight? It would be helpful to see the tables or at least samples of them.

Comment: I think there was an module already there, but you may've to tweak it some. As it works on the `cart` & `checkout` page to calculate/add/subtract the cost based on weight & location.
http://www.getclearthinking.com/formula-based-shipping

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin --> Settings -->Localisation -->Geo Zones
Create your geo zones and then head over to Extensions --> modules--> shipping
Select weight based shipping
Click on your zone, add weights and prices in this format:
250:200.00, 500:400.00, 1000:800.00 (weight:price)
Enable the zones and save.